# Are all data structures implemented with arrays and linked structures?

Tags: java, arrays, structure

I'm studying data structures in Java and so far, all of them are implemented with either an **array**, a **linked structure** or both. By linked structure I mean all kinds of structures, where a node can have one or more links to other nodes.

So, is it true, that in a language like Java these two data structures are the only ones that are used for implementing other data structures? I wonder if there is some other basic data structure. Or is there some theorem that proves that all data structures boil down to these two?

Comment: All data structures have data and a way (or ways) to reference that data. You can reference data by an offset or by "absolute" location. There's (typically) no other options.

Comment: If you equate "linked list" to "whatever can be implemented with references", then you're throwing an incredibly wide net. And if you add "arrays" as the other option then yes, I believe these two will cover all possible implementations of ADTs. But that doesn't really **say** much, since *what you do with them* can vary wildly.

Comment: It's a little bit like asking "Does all music really boil down to vibrating air at various frequencies?" Yes, it does, but that doesn't really tell you *anything interesting* about music.

Comment: In fairness, that noise is just vibrating air is kinda interesting.

Comment: @DaveNewton I just wonder if Information theory or Computer Science have something to say about it. Some formal answer or theorem.

Comment: You defined "linked list" so it covers anything that references data--seems tautological.

Comment: @DaniilKirichenko "linked structures" is very different from "linked lists" (as was the original version of the question). The "theorem" probably boils down to "everything must be in a computer's memory. You need to get those memory addresses somehow: by storing them (a "link") or by computing them (array base address + offset). And memory can be viewed as one big array with base address 0).

Answer (score 0):

Map is a very efficient and useful data structure provided by many platforms.
Set is another one.Both are efficient in terms of time complexity

Comment: That avoids the question: maps and sets have an implementation.

Comment: True but their impls. are not array based.

Comment: (They can be, but.) So they use some form of absolute reference, which falls into the OP's extended definition of a linked list?

Comment: Is that applicable for a SET as well? no index and no insertion order?

Comment: How do you think sets are implemented? (Not asking to be rude, just think there might be a disconnect.)

Comment: Thanks.Not offended at all. https://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/HashSet-source.html

Comment: Ok, and how are hash maps implemented?

Comment: /**
 136:    * Array containing the actual key-value mappings.
 137:    * Package visible for use by nested and subclasses.
 138:    */
 139:   transient HashEntry<K, V>[] buckets;

Comment: So an array. This is what I was getting at: the OP is asking if there are any data structures not derived from arrays and linked lists (with their extended def of "linked list").

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately yes. You could even go one step further and claim that everything is implemented with an "array". Let me explain why.

Memory is a bunch of bytes. Many, many bytes in modern computers (e.g. 68,719,476,736 bytes in a beefy laptop and many many more in a server). Usually, you don't address specific bytes, but larger units, e.g. 4 bytes can represent the common 32-bit integer. 8 bytes can hold a double-precision floating point number.

An array is a contiguous space in memory with many values in it. Each value in an array is the same size, which makes it quite efficient to access a single value, by taking the start address of the array and adding the offset (the index) multiplied by the size of your value (your data type, e.g. an integer = 4 bytes).

What if you assume that the start address of your array is 0 and the data type is "byte"? Now you can pretend all of your memory is one big array. And if you read 8 consecutive bytes from that big array, you have a 64 bit "long" value. A long value can be interpreted as offset for your big array (i.e. your memory). Congratulations, you can now add "pointers" or "references" to your array, allowing you to build linked data structures.

Linked data structures such as a linked list, which is just a special case of a binary tree with only one side of each node set to the next value. If you generalize a tree you get a graph. A graph allows cycles, which a tree does not. And once you can represent a graph, you can basically represent anything and everything.

So basically you have contiguous memory blocks, a.k.a. an array; and memory which points to memory elsewhere, but you could consider this just being an offset in one big array.

PS Arrays are an abstraction too. They only exist for us humans to write code that is easy to understand. Compilers will turn arrays into memory accesses. CPUs executing your code will never know that this piece of code was an array initially; CPUs only care about memory addresses (and registers).

Comment: It seems to me, that if we talk about a data structure inside memory, an offset is a separate thing from an address. They differ in locality. Offset is much more local in an array, than an address to some distant chunk of memory. If I understand correctly, this locality of the offset allows for better caching and speed, for example. To answer my own question, I guess there are other fundamental data structures. For example, addresses to other nodes don't have to be stored in memory at all. They can be calculated by some function. Still, I think there is more to this, than I currently see.

Comment: @DaniilKirichenko semantics :) And yes, offsets (which map to memory-locations) don't have to be stored, they can be computed. A [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) is a data structure which computes the offsets to the child nodes in the trees. The backing storage is still an array (which maps to a contiguous space in memory).

Answer (score 0):

These are considered to be basic Data structures from where a newbie can start learning. There are others Data Structures as well Like HashMaps, Sets, Lists. While solving complex problems one or more of these basic Data Structures are used. My Suggestion is to just learn basic Data structures and try to explore there applications in java programming. By doing that, you can easily understood which Data Structure to implement in a specific problem. Implementation would become easy once you learn basic ones with their applications well.